# Functions. True or False?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

For the following statements, I need to either prove it is true, or find a counterexample to demonstrate it is false.

Here is what I have done for each one:

(a) If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is an even function, then the function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $g(x) = -f(x)$ is also an even function.

True.

$$\begin{align}
g(x) &= -f(x) \\
g(-x) &= -f(-x) \\
      &= -f(x) \\
      &= g(x) \text{ which is even.}
\end{align}$$

(b) If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is an odd function, then $f$ is injective.

False.

Let $f(x) = \sin(x).$

$$\begin{align}
f(-x) &= \sin(-x) \\
      &= -\sin(x) \\
      &= -f(x)
\end{align}$$

$\sin(x)$ is odd but not injective.

(c) For all real numbers $x \in [0, 1],$ $\sin^{-1} x + \cos^{-1} x = \pi/2.$

True.

Let $\sin^{-1}(x) = \theta.$

$$\begin{align}
x &= \sin\theta \\
  &= \cos(\pi/2 - \theta) \\
\cos^{-1} x &= \pi/2 - \theta \\
\cos^{-1} x &= \pi/2 - \sin^{-1} x \\
\cos^{-1} x + \sin^{-1} x = \pi/2
\end{align}$$
Are these correct?

Comment: Please learn and use MathJax. On March 26 you wrote in a comment: "Thank you for formatting my question better and your help. I was unaware of that program but will make use of it in the future." Still you didn't use it today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your answers are all correct.

A couple of things though:

For the last line of (a), I would write "$ =g(x).$ Therefore $g(x)$ is even.", not "$=g(x)$ which is even."

For (b) you could say how you know/why you think $\sin(x)$ is not injective.

(c) I think is fine, although you could give more detail about the domain and range of the functions throughout your working.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help!